# calling json-rpc via curl

Tags: curl, bitcoin

I'am running Bitcoin-qt 0.8.6.1-beta on Qt 4.8.3 on windows 7 64.

below is my .conf content in %appdata%/bitcoin folder

```
rpcuser=bitcoinrpc
rpcpassword=ahything
rpcallowip=127.0.0.1
rpcallowip=192.168.*.*
rpcport=9332 
server=1
daemon=0
addnode=69.164.218.197
```

using curl 7.26.0 (i686-pc-mingw32), I run the following command:

```
curl --user 'bitcoinrpc' --data-binary '{"jsonrpc":"1.0","id":"curltext","method":"getinfo","params":[]}' -H 'content-type:text/plain;' http://127.0.0.1:8332
```

the pc ask for host password.

I have tried the .conf password and the PC password (which is the one I log into my PC)

I always get error 401 (unauthorized) result.

Can anyone advice me where did I went wrong or how do I know which password it refer to?

TIA

Regards,
KK Gian

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the '' around the username

eg:

```
curl --user bitcoinrpc --data-binary '{"jsonrpc":"1.0","id":"curltext","method":"getinfo","params":[]}' -H 'content-type:text/plain;' http://127.0.0.1:8332
```